# Javascript repeating countdown to Midday every Friday

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Im after some code which will display days, hours and minutes which counts down the days, hours and minutes left til midday every Friday?

(When midday friday is reached I would like the counter to start again to countdown to the next Friday midday, so the timer repeats over and over?)

Not sure  how to go about doing this as I am relatively new to JS

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Not putting this as an answer but if you are allowed to use jquery then there is a plugin called JQuery.Countdown that will basically do this for you.

Comment: There are many, many questions and answers here about timers, e.g. [*Javascript Countdown*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004939/javascript-countdown). Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of questions here on timers and countdowns, you should be able to work out something basic from them. A very simple countdown to noon next Friday is:

```js
function update(){

  // Get current date and time
  var today = new Date();

  // Get number of days to Friday
  var dayNum = today.getDay();
  var daysToFri = 5 - (dayNum < 5? dayNum : dayNum - 7);
  
  // Get milliseconds to noon friday
  var fridayNoon = new Date(+today);
  fridayNoon.setDate(fridayNoon.getDate() + daysToFri);
  fridayNoon.setHours(12,0,0,0);
  // Round up ms remaining so seconds remaining matches clock
  var ms = Math.ceil((fridayNoon - today)/1000)*1000;
  var d =  ms / 8.64e7 | 0;
  var h = (ms % 8.64e7) / 3.6e6 | 0;
  var m = (ms % 3.6e6)  / 6e4 | 0;
  var s = (ms % 6e4)    / 1e3 | 0;
  
  // Return remaining 
  return d + 'd ' + h + 'h ' + m + 'm ' + s + 's';
}

// Run update just after next full second
function runUpdate() {
  var el = document.getElementById('toFriday');
  el.innerHTML = update();
  setTimeout(runUpdate, 1020 - (Date.now()%1000));
}

 runUpdate();
```

```html
<div>Remaining to noon next Friday: <span id="toFriday"></span>
```

This is a very basic implementation and will skip when it goes over a daylight saving boundary (which can be avoided), but it should suit for a simple countdown where the hours remaining is not critical. It will only be wrong for a short time:

- in places where daylight saving is observed,
- on the two days of the year where daylight saving changes have an effect, and
- if the change is not at midnight

Comment: thanks, how can I use this script in my page? do I need JQuery, I have copied the script exactly as is, however it does not run? Many thanks for your help it is very much appreciated! @RobG

Comment: You need to run `runUpdate()` when the page has loaded. The code works in browsers back to and including IE 6.

Comment: @RobG what number 1020 present in `setTimeout(runUpdate, 1020 - (Date.now()%1000));` ?